# ECS task with execution role - token expired

Tags: java, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS task definition with a task execution role declared that has read/write access to an S3 bucket. This seems to happen irregularly, and, I am not sure what is triggering it, but I have seen errors come out of the container in regards to the token being expired:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The provided token has expired.
```

Is something defined incorrectly in the building of the S3 client? From the Spring configuration:

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 amazonS3Client() {
  return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
}
```

From [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/security-iam-roles.html):

> Newer versions of the AWS SDKs automatically fetch these credentials from the AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI environment variable when making AWS API calls.

> The output includes an access key-pair consisting of a secret access key ID and a secret key which your application uses to access AWS resources. It also includes a token that AWS uses to verify that the credentials are valid. By default, credentials assigned to tasks using task roles are valid for six hours. After that, they are automatically rotated by the Amazon ECS container agent.